# why am i getting every time the "Site Behavior: Navigation" for my android app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob

Admob always saying "Site Behavior: Navigation" by showing below screenshots.

[1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EviEr.png)
[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFD6l.png)

i made almost all changes and also i removed Interstial Ad. but still not getting why admob not lifting restriction.
any idea why ??

here link of my app: [my App link On playStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saheb.allinonevideodownloader).
now i am about to cry and frusted also. it will be my 11th attempt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article you will find your issue
[Admob policy](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdisallowed-example-user-launches-app%2Cdisallowed-example-user-exits-app%2Cdisallowed-example-recurring-interstitials%2Cdisallowed-example-interstitial-launches-when-opening-app)

Comment: i have read and did these already and again faced the restriction from Admob. now  i have even removed all Ads and rquested review again. but still admob not lifting restriction

Comment: First watch screen shot on admob then sort out which screen have problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Saheb Shaikh maybe your app is producing crash so you got this error. Please remove that crash they will send you screen shot please watch that screen shot and make sure that screen does not have any issue.